# Controlling camera shutter in android

Tags: android, camera, shutter

I want to close the camera shutter and then take a blind image. Is it possible in android.

In general the shutter opens, the sensor is exposed, shutter closes and then we get the image. I want to change this sequence. I want the shutter to remain close permanently and still I should be able to get images. Is it possible in android?

Answer (score 0):

If the shutter is close, you will get a complete black image. So you may construct such a black image yourself in your code.

Comment: Theoretically we will get a complete black image with all pixel value '0', but actually some of the pixels may have small non zero noise values. I want to analyse these black images generated by camera